# Programmatically Add/Remove displays on macOS

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-services, low-level-api

I'm looking for an API to add and remove displays to/from the system. I've found the [Quartz Display Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_display_services), but that API mainly lets you modify existing displays for the sake of fullscreen mode for apps and games.

For example, I would like to (via software) disable a display that's currently plugged in, while it is still plugged in. (Kind of like mounting and unmounting for drives)

Comment: I don't recall ever having encountered an API that does what you're looking for. It might be helpful if you let us know whether or not you care about being able to distribute your app through the App Store (which rules out private API usage).

Comment: I'm open to anything, preferably first-party, if possible